# Yii2 logout Method Not Allowed (#405)

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, adminlte

I'm using adminlte advanced template for backend. I want to add logout in the left column.

I've read other posts and I understand I've to add data method post. I've added it in following line in left.php file, but it doesn't work. How to make it work?

```
<?= dmstr\widgets\Menu::widget(
    [
        'options' => ['class' => 'sidebar-menu tree', 'data-widget'=> 'tree'],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Logout', 'icon' => 'file-code-o', 'url' => ['/site/logout'], 'data-method'=>'post'],
    ]
    ) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extending the [`yii\widgets\Menu`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-menu#%24linkTemplate-detail) and you need to specify the `template` to modify or add any attribute to the link as the `data-method="post"` needs to be added to your link you should change the code to the following

```
echo  
    dmstr\widgets\Menu::widget(
        [
            'options' => ['class' => 'sidebar-menu tree', 'data-widget'=> 'tree'],
            'items' => [
                ['label' => 'Logout', 'icon' => 'file-code-o', 'url' => ['/site/logout'], 'template'=>'<a href="{url}" data-method="post">{label}</a>'],
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a form in to your click field:

```
$items[] = [
    [
        'label' => 'Logout', 
        'icon' => 'file-code-o', 
        'url' => ['/site/logout'],
        'template' => Html::beginForm(array('site/logout')) . 
             Html::submitButton('Logout') . Html::endForm(),
    ],
];
```

Comment: this is incorrect the `options` will add the `data-method` to the `li` and not the link

Comment: I agree with you, my mistake, options does add attributes to wrapper tag.